# How do I do a case-insensitive replace all for a string?

Tags: apex, string, regular-expressions

I've got a project where I'd like to replicate some of the internal merge field functionality so users can build a link and it'd be really helpful if I could do a case-insensitive string replaceAll.

For example, if I want to replace `{!id}` or any of it's case variations I could do

```
return input.replaceAll('\\{![iI][dD]}\\', value);
```

While I can make do with creating a function to built a regex for any particular input pattern  (nevermind the potential issues with script statements) it'd be great if I could emulate how `sed` works (the 'i' indicates case insensitive).  For example:

```
sed 's/\{!id\}/replacement/i' inputfile.txt
```

Anyone have any tips on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The option to replace case insensitive regex in java is Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE, which can also be specified as (?i)

(http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/Why-Pattern-CASE-INSENSITIVE-not-detectable/td-p/204337)

```
String srcStr = '{!id} value {!Id} is not {!ID}';
String replaceToken = '(?i)\\{!id\\}';
System.debug('REPLACEMENT ' + srcStr.replaceAll(replaceToken, ''));
System.assertEquals('  value  is not ', srcStr.replaceAll(replaceToken, ''));
```

Comment: For a 'Mortarboard' encore ;)

Answer (score 2):

Just curious can you not convert the string to a particular case?

say

```
String ex = 'Upper';
ex.toLowerCase();
```

(or)

```
ex.toUpperCase()
```

Examples from the official documentation -

```
String s1 = 'ThIs iS hArD tO rEaD';
System.assertEquals('this is hard to read',
s1.toLowerCase());

String myString1 = 'abcd';
String myString2 = 'ABCD';
myString1 = 
   myString1.toUpperCase();
Boolean result = 
   myString1.equals(myString2);
System.assertEquals(result, true);
```

Comment: The string gets displayed to the end user, so I'd need to convert it back to it's original case ...

Comment: Store the original in a string - have a separate variable where you upper/lowercase the values... do your work... replace with original String value?

Comment: I would agree to the above comment and since you mentioned the {!Id} field FYI : doing the conversion of Id would result in troubles sometimes if you use the 18 digit ID because 15 digit is a case sensitive ID http://forceguru.blogspot.com/2010/12/how-salesforce-18-digit-id-is.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use other salesforce string methods for the replacement.
For example:

```
String inputString = 'Welcome {!Contact.Name}';
String toReplace = 'contact.name';  //Can use describe methods and get all fields for the relevant object/s

while(inputString.indexOfCaseIgnoreCase(toReplace) != -1){
    Integer indexStartReplace = inputString.indexOfCaseIgnoreCase(toReplace);
    Integer indexEndReplace = indexStartReplace + toReplace.length()
    inputString = inputString.replace(inputString.substring(indexStartReplace, indexEndReplace), '');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Salesforce Apex String replacement: Use the following regex to ignore case sensitivity in replace operation.

```
***//Use (?i) regex to make the replacement process to avoid case sensitive***   
String message = 'Welcome Home';
String searchText = 'home';
String newText = 'World';     
               
String convertedText = message.replaceAll('(?i)'+searchText, newText); 
System.debug('convertedText>> '+ convertedText);
***//Output: convertedText>> Welcome World***
```

Comment: Honestly, why do you think your answer (to a question that is 10 years old) does contribute anything to the accepted answer?!

Comment: I posted something, that has a different way than others in this question forum. so when people are searching they might get different ways to solve their problems.


To be frank, do you think every problem has only one solution? it's not about acceptable or not.